# How do I return a char from a function that uses winsock to recv from socket?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-xp, winsock2

My application is crashing when I try printing the buffer. Otherwise, it works fine.
This is the code:

**irc.h**

```
  class IRC
            {
              public:
                      void sockconnect(char * hName, int portNum);
                          void sockwrite(char* sendbuf);
                          char sockread(void);
                          bool connected;
                  private:
                          WSADATA wsaData;
                          SOCKET m_socket;
                          sockaddr_in clientService;
                          LPHOSTENT hostEntry;

};
```

**irc.cc**

```
char IRC::sockread(void)

  {
    int result;
    char buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
        result = recv(m_socket, buffer, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);

        if (result > 0) {
             return *buffer;
              }
          else if (result == 0)
              {
             connected = false;
                 return *buffer;
              }
          else {
         printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
         return *buffer;
        }

   }
```

**main.cc**

```
 IRC client;

 while (client.connected == true) {
     char buffer = client.sockread();
         if (buffer == NULL)
           break;


        printf ("Buffer: %s\n",buffer);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the first character use

```
printf ("Buffer: %c\n",buffer);
```

If you want to print the whole then sockread should return the whole buffer, not the first character. For that you will need to return the address of the first element of the buffer which in this case should already be dynamically allocated.

```
printf ("Buffer: %s\n",buffer);
```

***Edit*** After thinking I think you want the latter for that change the `sockread()` function in the following way:

- change the return type from `char` to `char*` or better `const char*`
- `char buffer[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];` to `char* buffer = new char[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];`
- `return *buffer`  to `return buffer`

Also, in this case don't forget to delete the buffer

```
const char* buffer = client.sockread(); //not char buffer as in your code
printf ("Buffer: %s\n",buffer);
delete [] buffer;
```

hth

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Isn't that what I'm doing already?

Comment: @thorvald: No, actually you are returning only the first character. See my edit

Comment: You are returning a single char(the first char in your buffer) and you are trying to print that char as as string (a nul terminated char*)

Comment: error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char'

Comment: @thorvald: Yeah well you should change sockread to return char* not char

Comment: Thanks, it works now but I'm a bit confused. I thought if you declare a function with char then it should return char? Sorry for the dumb question but this is my first time with C++.

Comment: @thorvald: Exacrly. In your previous version your function was declared/defined to return char and it returned char. But char is a single character. You need to return a whole array right? One of the ways is to return the address to the first element of a null-terminated character sequence. It should be new's inside the function because otherwise it would be destroyed as soon as the function exits... Anyway I can't explain whole C++ in one comment. But I strongly recommend that you read S.Lippman's C++ Primer. The best C++ book for beginner/intermediate. And even experts can keep it as a ref

Comment: @Armen: It wasn't me, but you should definitely change to std::string. If he doesn't grasp pointer basics, he's not gonna track his own memory, and needs all the extra type-safety that C++ offers. Also, I just got downvoted too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use std::string. You can't return that buffer- it's on the local stack. Even if you succeeded in returning an actual pointer to it instead of just a single character, which is what you have done, then it would be out of scope and the data within it invalid.

std::string takes care of all of these problems. You just use it, and it's done. You have other problems too, like invalid returning of a buffer when actually it's failed. This is what exceptions are for.

```
std::string IRC::sockread()
{
    std::string s;
    s.resize(DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
    int result = recv(m_socket, &s[0], DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);

    if (result > 0) {
        return s;
    } else if (result == 0) {
        connected = false;
    } else {
        std::cout << "recv failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Socket connection failed!");
}
```

Comment: I tried this example but it doesn't print anything when I call it from the main function.  std::string s;
 s.resize(512);
 s = client.sockread();
 printf("%s\n",s); but it prints "Ìü" everytime.

The example in the other answer works.

Comment: @thorvald: THat's because you're supposed to use std::cout, as I showed, not printf. Also, you don't have to resize the string outside the function. You can just do `std::cout << client.sockread();` or `std::string s = client.sockread();`.

Comment: It doesn't compile if I use std::cout.

error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @thorvald: Don't forget to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Oh, I was including string.h instead of string. :/

Comment: What about if I wanted the recv function to read the socket line by line? Should I read each character until it reaches the newline character and then join them together and return? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @thorvald: You could do that. I don't really know much about sockets so can't be very helpful.